# Android AlertDialog topPanel view pushes content off screen

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

For some reason, all of my AlertDialogs are pushing the content view off screen.  The first example just shows simple text:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle(R.string.welcome_title)
    .setIcon(null)
    .setMessage(R.string.welcome_message)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton(null, null)
    .setCancelable(true)
    .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    })
    .create().show();
```

And the second is to show an HTML file from my assets:

```
public static void showHtmlDialog(Activity activity, String url, CharSequence title, CharSequence buttonText) {
    View layout = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.scrollable_web_view, null);
    WebView webView = (WebView)layout.findViewById(R.id.web_content);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    webView.setWebViewClient(WebUtils.createStandardWebViewClient(activity));

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        .setView(layout)
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setIcon(null)
        .setNegativeButton(buttonText, getDialogNegativeBtnListener())
        .setTitle(title)
        .create()
        .show();
}
```

Looking at the view hierarchy, I can see that the topPanel (title and icon) take up pretty much the whole screen, and the content is there--just off screen (screenshot [here](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/268/alertdialogissue.png/)).

I suppose I should mention that I'm using GreenDroid, though I haven't had this issue before. Targeting Android 4.0.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out--the problem was with my theme.  The theme set for the Activity in question had:

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/main_bg</item>
```

Removing that line from the theme put everything back in place.